# Strange binding/validation behaviour when binding select list to booleans

Tags: angularjs

Can anybody explain me the following strange binding/validation behaviour when binding a select list to boolean values?

Selecting "Yes" (true) works as expected. Selecting "No" (false) obviously does not:

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mhu23/ATRQG/14/

```
$scope.trueFalseOptions = [{
    value: true,
    label: 'Yes'
}, {
    value: false,
    label: 'No'
}];

<select name="parameter" required ng-model="myModel" ng-options="x.value as x.label for x in trueFalseOptions"></select>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would like to be able to select "Yes" or "No" from a dropdown list. The values of the option items should be true or false (boolean, not string).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the `required` directive does not consider a value of `false` to be valid and sets your model value to `undefined`:

[Github source link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/861e0c75bd60706d1fd4076d6a7b205c18bb63c9/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1219):

```
  var validator = function(value) {
    if (attr.required && (isEmpty(value) || value === false)) {
      ctrl.$setValidity('required', false);
      return;
    } else {
      ctrl.$setValidity('required', true);
      return value;
    }
  };
```

Here are some options:

1. Use `ngRequired` instead of `required`. This lets you choose a custom required expression like: `ng-required="!(myModel == true || myModel == false)"`. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATRQG/18/) with an example.
2. You can create your own modified `required` directive that will allow false
3. Bind to something else (1 and 0 or "true" and "false" like you mentioned)

---

Also note you may want to add an empty option value so the first item doesn't say "Yes" after you select it:

```
<select name="parameter" ng-model="myModel" ng-options="x.value as x.label for x in trueFalseOptions">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: After debugging for 2 hours you just saved me at least 2 more. Thanks!